# JavaScript Error/Bug from Chrome on iPad/iPhone

Tags: google-chrome, runtime-error, javascript

I ran into this JavaScript error: `TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '__gChrome.suggestion.hasNextElement')`

I have absolutely no idea where it came from or how it is reproduced. All I know is that it came from three different, unrelated (as in, different companies) people, months apart, all from different pages on our product.

`__gChrome.suggestion.hasNextElement` is not in our code anywhere so I think it's either a Chrome issue or an extension issue.

All the information I have about this is this (that I can show, the information that is omitted isn't useful anyways):

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '__gChrome.suggestion.hasNextElement')
Function: send()
Rendering Engine: Mozilla
Browser: Netscape
Version: 5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/33.0.1750.21 Mobile/11D167 Safari/9537.53 (05200A98-5316-4F45-882D-7E55DB80E9D4)
Cookies: true
Platform: iPad
User Agent Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 7_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/33.0.1750.21 Mobile/11D167 Safari/9537.53 (05200A98-5316-4F45-882D-7E55DB80E9D4)
```

I have tried Googling it but can't find anything. Just curious if anyone has seen this or knows anything about it or can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Looks to me like your errors are coming from Safari, not Chrome.

Comment: @Pointy On IOS, Chrome uses Safari.

Comment: @Pointy How do you figure that? I mean I know it's Apple, but a lot of people have Chrome for their browsers. Also, the error says "`__gChrome`". Not disagreeing, just curious why you say that.

Comment: @epascarello oh right; durr.

Comment: I believe that the chrome ios app is actually using ios safari under the hood. But the error is not present in ios safari?

Comment: If it's not in your code, it's probably a plugin or other part of the browser.

Comment: it's a implementation issue in chrome https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=590375 (happens when autofill is enabled, only on chrome)